# Regex UK Postcode Javascript Space Issues

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox-addon

Currently I have a JavaScript program that is using Regex to detect UK postcodes.
At the minute it is just displaying them in an alert.
I am currently struggling to detect Postcodes with a space. 
For example SW12 5BV, BR3 8DD 
It also needs to accept Postcodes without spaces such as DE148NV, JN24HH.
Current Regex Code:

```
var postcodePattern = /[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}/i;
                var resultPost = postcodePattern.test(words[i]);
                if(resultPost)  {   
                alert("Postcode detected: " + words[i]);
```

I have also tried various other UK postcode regex which to no avail. 
Example

```
//var postcodePattern = /^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {0,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR ?0AA)$/
```

I also have a function which removes all HTML Tags after the regex has taken place which has affected previous regex.

```
removeHTMLTags: function(aString){

        var strInputCode = aString;

        var strTagStrippedText = strInputCode.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, " ");
        strTagStrippedText = strTagStrippedText.replace(/&nbsp/g," ");

        //Remove some escape characters
        strTagStrippedText = strTagStrippedText.replace(/\(|\)|\{|\}|\[|\]|\?|\*|\+|\||\//ig," ");

        //Replace multilple white spaces with single white space
        strTagStrippedText = strTagStrippedText.replace(/\s+/g," ");

        return strTagStrippedText; },
```

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: The regex only manages to find Postcodes that are without spaces. Example TN124IU. If a space is used it does not detect the UK Postcode. Example: TN12 4IU.

Comment: Can you show your regex failing in a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), where it's easier for us to play with, and correct, it?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as putting your space inside a character class? I am assuming you are only allowing a single space based on the re-formatting code in the second code block.

```
var postcodePattern = /[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[ ]{0,1}[0-9][A-Z]{2}/i;
            var resultPost = postcodePattern.test(words[i]);
            if(resultPost)  {   
            alert("Postcode detected: " + words[i]);
```

As per the comments, you are splitting you input on spaces as well here:

```
bodyContentsStrippedTags.split(/\s+|\,|\&|\||\/|\?|\!|\:|;|"/);
```

with the \s+ in your split regex. This means postal codes with a space get passed to your regex as two separate array items and not a single string.

Comment: I have tried this and again it does not pick up the postcodes with a space. The alert is not displayed. It seems to only display when there no space.

Comment: Strange - I double checked for a stupid mistake in the above and this works in a regex tester... Are you inspecting your value for words[i] immediately before calling your regex to confirm it is not being otherwise strangely formatted in your above code?

Comment: Yeah I did the same with the previous regex's i have used. This is the code before as this is a firefox addon which scans a webpage for a postcode.

Comment: var vrs_getWin = document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow;
   var bodyContents = vrs_getWin.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
   
   var bodyContentsStrippedTags = namespace_checkwebpage.removeScriptBlock(bodyContents);
   bodyContentsStrippedTags = namespace_checkwebpage.removeHTMLTags(bodyContentsStrippedTags);
   
   var words = bodyContentsStrippedTags.split(/\s+|\,|\&|\||\/|\?|\!|\:|;|"/); 
   
   for (i =0; i< words.length; i++){
    if( words[i].length > 1 ){

Comment: Note in the above (without being able to easily read it) looks like you are splitting on \s Are you sure you are passing what you think you are passing to the validation regex? try an: `alert("Input: " + words[i]);` right before the call to `postcodePattern.test`

Comment: When using that alert it is displaying the postcode as two separate words for instance TN12 new word: 6NU when should be picking up as TN12 6NU as full postcode.

Comment: Thought so: it is this line splitting your values on the space: bodyContentsStrippedTags.split(/`\s+`|\,|\&|\||\/|\?|\!|\:|;|"/);